# Two Physical Database Servers for online (web/ecommerce) and store POS logic

Tags: php, sql, database, load-balancing

One of my client has an ecommerce site with a database server catering it.

Now we are going to integrate POS Logic (selling from store through Sales Associate) with eCommerce Site.

In his raw requirements mentioned to use separate physical database server for POS related sale/return transactions in cash-register for POS (and sales associate) specific reports.

He wants business logic to maintain same transactions also on Existing eCommerce Server Database. Why? he answers this as below:

The POS SERVER will keep track of all sales transactions made in the store. Some of the reasons for doing this are:

---

1. Offload some retail store reporting to the POS SERVER
2. Sales associates records are stored on the POS SERVER not the e-commerce server and we need to produce sales associate reports.
3. We need to provide a failover function in case of network interruption so we need a sales journal to post transactions to on the POS SERVER.

The following database tables store the sales:

```
sales_transactions_journal
sales_transactions_journal_lines
sales_transactions_journal_sales_associate_chain
```

My gutt feeling is that executing same database transaction twice, each for each separate physical Database Servers will not be a good idea. I want to oppose this design because i feel that:

1. if we run same query twice for each DB Server then we will need to write fault-tolerance and synchronization code.
2. Customer + Store (like, which customer prefer to shop from which store) Specific reports will require to store cusomer information with store-specific server to answer above query. Hence we would not only be copying sale transaction but also customer info for whome sale took place on POS.

   I want you to add any more solid concrete points so that i can convince my Project Manager and Client that this will not be a good approach to achieve reporting+load balancing, instead some other techniques like Data Replicatoin, Sharding etc would be better.

Comment: I would question your gut.  This isn't uncommon.

Comment: Is it a good idea that we duplicte POS sales transaction table on two physical servers and use PHP-based business logic layer to execute two same sales transactions one for each physical database server? (only for the reasons mentioned above. I feel that same objectives can be achieved through Database Replication Mechanism on Database Servers level ( which automatically and efficiently do replication and fault-tolerance with mcuh better performance)